# How do I apply sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range? GCP K8

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application that ICMP Pings out to IP addresses from GCP K8s running on AutoPilot.

I tried setting the below first but it turns out GCP K8s on AutoPilot disable that permission if you add it.

```
 securityContext:
    capabilities:
      add: ["NET_RAW"]
```

Next I tried setting net.ipv4.ping_group_range like the below in my deployment file.

```
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true 
    seccompProfile: 
      type: RuntimeDefault
    sysctls:
    - name: kernel.shm_rmid_forced
      value: "1"
    - name: net.ipv4.ping_group_range
      value: "0           200000000"
```

But the above gives me the error below when I try and deploy it.

```
strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.sysctls"
```

I've also tried

```
  command: ["/bin/sh"]
  args:
    - -c
    - sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range=0 2000000
```

In my deployment file but that gives me an error of permission denied when the container tries to start.

Is it possible to ICMP Ping an IP address from a GCP K8 AutoPilot cluster or how do I apply sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range correctly?

Answer (score 1):

GKE Autopilot clusters always use [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#limitations) with containerd as their node image. The Container-Optimized OS kernel is locked down in autopilot clusters so that you cannot perform write operations on it as it is constrained to only read-only mode.

Therefore the cluster is disabling permissions to set some values to the parameters in the kernel, as the kernel is locked-down.

In order to modify the attributes according to your need, you can use a [**GKE Standard Cluster**](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-zonal-cluster) which provides flexibility.